# Positioning content in webview using javascript function in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, scroll

I have a problem with some things related to javascript and webview in android. I need to set on top some text that I have in a webView. I fill the webview with an epub. Each part of text to set on top, has the following tag:

```
<input name="chapterNumber" type="hidden" value="chapter1" id="chapter1">
```

and above  y have the following javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function findPos(obj) {
              var curtop = 0;
              if (obj.offsetParent) {
                   do {
                   curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                        return [curtop];
              }
            }
    });
  //]]>
  </script>
```

In the activity I have:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
            {  
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById('chapter1')))");

            }  
        });
```

But the scroll doesn't work. The chapter 1 is not positioned on top. How could I change this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could resolve it! First of all on the epub file put this javascript code: [code]  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
                function scrollToPosition(obj){
                        location='#'+obj; 
                                                
                } 
  /*]]>*/
  </script> [/code]

Comment: In the activity:
[code]webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
                {  
                  webView.loadUrl("javascript:scrollToPosition('"+Config.getInstance().getStringProperty(Config.PROPERTY_CHAPTER_SELECTED)+"')");
       
                }

            });   [/code]

Comment: And in each mark I put (epub file):
[CODE]<p><a id="chapter1"></a></p>[/CODE]
...
[CODE]<p><a id="chapter2"></a></p>[/CODE]
... etc